# vim: how to substitute like this situation

Tags: vim, substitution

The sample for substituting:

```
hello world (one) hello world (two two) hello world (three three three)
```

The result I want:

```
hello world $one# hello world $two two# hello world $three three three#
```

I've tried to use:

```
s/(\(\w\\+\s*\))/$\1#/g
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You MUST use a single substitution, don't you? Otherwise `s/(/$/g` and `s/)/#/g` will do

Comment: I tested before posting, using vim version 7.4.430 and the default configuration of vim on Debian testing.

Comment: @StilesCrisis By default, Vim reverses the meaning of escaping in many cases; i.e. it treats many characters literally that are considered "special" in more standard regex flavors, and the special regex meaning is only used if the character is escaped. In the case of parentheses, they only have the "grouping" effect when escaped. (The \v or "very magic" flag can be used to make Vim regex more like a standard regex flavors.)

Comment: Cool. Had no idea vim was a special snowflake for regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing these two simple substitutions is a lot more intuitive and a lot faster than wasting your time trying to come up with a single one:

```
:s/(/\$/g
:s/)/#/g
```

Anyway:

```
:s/(\([^)]\+\))/\$\1#/g
```

**The search part:** we are looking for an opening parenthese, followed by one or more characters that are not closing parentheses that we put in a capture group, followed by a closing parenthese.

**The replacement part:** we replace with a dollar sign, followed by our capture group, followed by an octothorpe.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. And I also get one answer above by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for everyone. I have woke out it.`:s/(\(\(\w*\s*\)*\))/$\1#/g`. The preceding command can give the right result I want.